# SQL converting month into Years and Months

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an **X** number of months, but I need to break it into xx years yy months in SQL.

For example: **31** months should be **2** years **7** months.

Is there any inbuilt function or something to help?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: [div](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [mod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use modulus to get the months and floor to get the years

```
 SELECT totalmonths, FLOOR(tottalmonths / 12) AS years, totalmonths % 12 as months
 FROM -- ...
```

Comment: No need to `FLOOR` as integer division truncates anyway

Comment: @MartinSmith -- Good point -- I'll leave it like this because some SQL platforms don't auto truncate

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
     SELECT 
       (months_column_name / 12) AS years, 
       (months_column_name % 12) AS months
       
  FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a solution the uses built-in functions, but I'd hardly call it helpful when olde fashioned arithmetic operators will provide the desired results in a much more concise manner, e.g. Hogan's answer.  [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=520b02f6534064d15a4b1df28e0201ed).

```
with
  SomeMonths as (
    -- Create some test data from 0 to 100.
    select 0 as Months
    union all
    select Months + 1
      from SomeMonths
      where Months < 100 ),
  CompleteDate as (
    -- Convert the number of months into a date based at 1 January 1.
    select Months, DateAdd( month, Months, Cast( '00010101' as Date ) ) as Sometime
      from SomeMonths )
  select Months,
    -- Make the number of years zero-based.
    Year( Sometime ) - 1 as TheYears,
    -- Make the number of months zero-based.
    Month( Sometime ) - 1 as TheMonths
    from CompleteDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there Unknown Coder,

I made some code here that will display the number of months and years..
It also has a more human friendly way of displaying the data, like in your example.
So that last one will display as "2 years 7 months" if your value was 31.

Here's my code with the temp database for testing:

```
Declare @monthtest TABLE
(
    NumOfMonths     int
);

INSERT INTO @monthtest (NumOfMonths) select 11
INSERT INTO @monthtest (NumOfMonths) select 13
INSERT INTO @monthtest (NumOfMonths) select 31

select 
cast(x1.NumOfMonths / 12 as int) as years,
(x1.NumOfMonths ) % 12 as months,

concat(
    cast(x1.NumOfMonths / 12 as int),
    (case when cast(x1.NumOfMonths / 12 as int) = 1 then ' year ' else ' years ' end ),
    (x1.NumOfMonths ) % 12,
    (case when (x1.NumOfMonths ) % 12 = 1 then ' month' else ' months' end )
) as combined

from @monthtest as x1
```

This will output as

| years | months | combined |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 11 | 0 years 11 months |
| 1 | 1 | 1 year 1 month |
| 2 | 7 | 2 years 7 months |